# Expectation of Componentwise Sinc of Multivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This question is related to [Expectation of Sinc of Standardnormal Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805101/expectation-of-sinc-of-standardnormal-distribution)

I want to compute

$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{\sin(Y_1) \sin(Y_2)}{Y_1Y_2} \right]$$

where $(Y_1, Y_2)$ is multivariate normally distributed with zero mean vector and $\operatorname{Var}(Y_1)=\operatorname{Var}(Y_2) = 1$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(Y_1, Y_2) = \rho$.

I tried to go at this problem as in the univariate case, i.e. simplify $\frac{\sin(Y_1)}{Y_1}$ using the Taylor expansion of $\sin$, computing the Cauchy product of the two resulting series and then pulling in the expectation into the sum which gives me

$$ \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{\sin(Y_1) \sin(Y_2)}{Y_1Y_2} \right] = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{1}{(2k+1)!(2(n-k)+1)!} \mathbb{E}[Y_1^{2k}Y_2^{2(n-k)}]. $$

However, I am not sure how to compute the mixed moments. I did some research already and found the [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02331888608801937) which seems to apply to this particular case but unfortunately the formula given in that paper is not really easy to evaluate given that the exponents depend on $k$ and $n$.

So I am wondering if anyone has an idea how to go at this problem instead. I already tried using polar coordinates for the computation of
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\sin(x) \sin(y)}{xy} f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$
where $f$ is the density of $(Y_1, Y_2)$ but that didn't lead me anywhere either.

EDIT: In reply to Metamorphy's answer:

I was able to compute
$$ \frac{1}{4} \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} \exp \Big\{ -\frac{1}{2} (t_1^2+t_2^2-2\rho t_1 t_2) \Big\}\ dt_1\ dt_2 \\
= 
\frac{1}{4} \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{2 \pi} \exp \Big\{ \frac{1}{2} (1-\rho^2)t_2^2 \Big\} \  \big[\Phi(1-\rho t_2) - \Phi(-1 - \rho t_2)\big] \ dt_2$$
where $\Phi$ is the cdf of a standardnormal distribution by rewriting the function dependent on $t_1$ as a density of a standardnormal distribution. However, I am not sure how to deal with the standardnormal cdf inside the second integral. I tried rewriting the remaining integral such that it resembles one of the integral of Gaussian functions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions) but I was not successful in doing that.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler integral representation results from $$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac12\int_{-1}^1 e^{itx}\,dt,$$ so that your expectation is $\frac14\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\phi(t_1,t_2)\,dt_1\,dt_2$, where $$\phi(t_1,t_2)=\mathbb{E}[\exp(it_1 Y_1+it_2 Y_2)]=\exp(-(t_1^2+t_2^2)/2-\rho t_1 t_2)$$ is the characteristic function of $(Y_1,Y_2)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I am not sure how to integrate this function especially because we are not integrating over the whole real line. I added what I computed so far to my original post since it did not fit into a comment.